# Event handler for canvas mouse enters while being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to implement a JQuery event listener for an HTML 5 canvas element where a mouse cursor enters the canvas while being clicked.

Comment: Check the link http://jsfiddle.net/tQyst/9/

Comment: You mean the mouse button is hold when cursor enter canvas?

Comment: There is a `.buttons` property on the `mousenter` event. Check that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter#Properties small browser support though :/

Answer (score 0):

Keep a flag when `mousedown` and `mouseup`, then check this when user hover on the canvas.

```js
var mouseDown = false;
$(document).mousedown(function() {
  mouseDown = true;
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
  mouseDown = false;
});

var canvasHover = false;
$('canvas').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('span').html(mouseDown ? 'true' : 'false');
});
```

```css
canvas {
  background:yellow;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<hr />
mouse is down: <span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind mousedown\mouseup events to `document`and mouseenter event on canvas.

I'd suggest to use capturing phase instead (which jQuery doesn't support) to avoid any propagation event stopped in some way.

See an example:

```js
 document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
   $(this).data('mouseHold', e.which);
 }, true);
 document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
   $(this).data('mouseHold', false);
 }, true);
 $('canvas').on('mouseenter', function() {
   if ($(document).data('mouseHold')) {
     console.log('holding mouse button ' + $(document).data('mouseHold'));
   }
 });
```

```css
canvas {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```